# how to use a while loop using strings in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm just trying to see if I can get a while loop to work using a string as the conditional. I'm trying to calculate the volume of several shapes and store them in a list depending on what shape the user entered and until the user enters 'quit' as a sentinel. when i ran my code the program just kept defaulting to the 'quit' branch and prompted for a new shape no matter what the user entered.

[image: The code]

Comment: Please add the code to your post (not an image, text version).

Comment: And the image is out of range anyway so I can't help format.